# Is unity keystore and version upgrade related?

Tags: unity-game-engine, keystore

I workd on Unity 2018.3.11 version and recently upgraded to 2019.4.18 LST.

However, i cant build APK because of wrong keystore password.

No matter how hard I try to enter the password I remember, I can't access keysotre.

I wonder if I remember the password incorrectly or if I upgrade the Unity version, I can't access the keystore I used before...  :(

Comment: Changing the unity version doesn't effect that. You are probably entering incorrect password.

Comment: thanks, I'll have to find the password again.